# Read specific data line by line

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to read data from a file in specific format.

file looks as follows

```
title:stack|content:overflow|metadata:53|comments:none
title:google|content:website|metadata:213|comments:Demos
```

I need to read this line by line and 
assign title variable with `title` value (`"stack"`), content with `content` value (`"overflow"`) for each line.

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        for scanner.Scan() {
                data := scanner.Text()
                data_arr := strings.Split(data, "|")

                for _, n := range data_arr {

                        data_subdoc := strings.Split(n, ":")
                        a, b := data_subdoc[0], data_subdoc[1]

                        fmt.Println(a, b)
```

But problem is I get data as (relation between title, content, metadata and comments for each line is missing)

```
title stack
content overflow
metadata 53
comments none
title google
content website
metadata 213 
comments Demos
```

But, I want something like:

```
stack overflow 53

if stack has 53:
    print comments (in this case, its 'none')

google website 213

if google has 213, print content (In this case, its 'website')
```

Comment: I see no relation betwwen the output you get and the output you want to generate. What is the expected output for the given input?

Comment: @LutzHorn I am unable to get relation for title, content, metadata and comments for each line. For instance, I want to print content + comments together.

Currently, I get content and comments as seperate line (due to for loop).
So, no relation is possible i think.

Comment: Collect the data from each line into a `struct` type. Let this type implement  [`Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer). Print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LutzHorn suggested, why not read your data into a struct? The code below does that using reflection (though without checking for existence or type of field).

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type Entry struct {
    Title    string
    Content  string
    Metadata string
    Comments string
}

func main() {
    var input string = `title:stack|content:overflow|metadata:53|comments:none
title:google|content:website|metadata:213|comments:Demos
`

    var result = make(map[string]Entry)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        data := scanner.Text()
        data_arr := strings.Split(data, "|")

        entry := Entry{}

        for _, n := range data_arr {

            data_subdoc := strings.Split(n, ":")
            key, value := data_subdoc[0], data_subdoc[1]

            fmt.Println(key, value)

            field := strings.Title(key)
            reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(&entry)).FieldByName(field).SetString(value)
        }

        result[entry.Metadata] = entry
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result["53"])
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result["213"])
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case, `result["53"].comments` is what i need :)